# Как удалить отступ между строками таблицы в html

Tags: html, css, table

Я постарался удалить все отступы но почему-то мужду строками отступ всё же существует.
Вот html

```
<table>
    <tr><td><img src="img/gta.jpg" alt=""></td>
    <td><img src="img/call.jpg" alt=""></td>
    <td><img src="img/cb.jpg" alt=""></td></tr>
    
    <tr><td><img src="img/pubg.jpg" alt=""></td>
    <td><img src="img/ff.jpg" alt=""></td>
    <td><img src="img/csgo.jpeg" alt=""></td></tr>
    
    <tr><td><img src="img/Among_Us.png" alt=""></td>
    <td><img src="img/bs.jpg" alt=""></td>
    <td><img src="img/mc.jpg" alt=""></td></tr>
</table>
```

И css:

```
table td{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

И ещё каждая картина размером 640 на 333 пикселя.

Comment: `line-height: 0` ?

Comment: проверь нормалайз, может, какие-то свойства пропущены. И лучше добавь ссылку на демо, проблема может быть вовсе не в таблице.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, по идее сработает, но ведь можно лучше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У картинок по умолчанию размещение по базовой линии (ну если это не таблица в документе в quirks-режиме), соответственно остаётся пустота.

Либо меняем отображение:

```
img {
  display: block;
}
```

Либо просто выравниваем:

```
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: @0xdb, готово :)